# How can I redirect users when they log into Drupal UNLESS they are placing an order?

Tags: drupal, redirect, ubercart

I want to redirect users when they log in to my site to a specific page. I currently do this in hook_user:

```
if($op == 'login') {
  drupal_goto('defaut');
}
```

This mostly works fine. However, I'm using Ubercart to take orders, and have it configured to automatically log in new users. This happens before the conditional action to update the order status to "Completed" is triggered. This means that when the user is logged in automatically, my hook_user redirects the user, and bypasses the remaining order processing.

At the moment, I'm working around this by checking debug_backtrace for the calling function uc_cart_checkout_complete somewhere in the call stack, but this sounds like a really dirty way to resolve it.

Can anyone suggest a cleaner way to achieve my conditional redirection without hacking great chunks of Ubercart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use hooks of ubercart (for example, hook_order, hook_cart etc of ubercart, see in ubercart\docs\hooks.php ), add `$_SESSION['no_redirect'] = true;` there, and change you redirection:

```
if($op == 'login' && !$_SESSION['no_redirect']) {
  unset($_SESSION['no_redirect']);
  drupal_goto('defaut');
}
```

Comment: It turns out that Ubercart already sets $_SESSION['new_user'] when it creates a new user account, so I can just test for that in my hook.